# What can be used to thionate a monosubstituted urea?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, organosulfur-compounds

I'm looking to make a thiourea from a monosubstituted urea. I haven't found any references that use Lawesson's Reagent, which I have been using for the thionation of di and trisubstituted ureas. Is there something that would prevent Lawesson's Reagent from working on a monosubstituted urea?

[image]

Comment: It's described at least in 1 patent: WO2004031161 and one article: Korkusuz, Elif; Yildirim, Ismail, Journal of Heterocyclic Chemistry, 2010, vol. 47, # 2, p. 472 - 476. But I'm not sure about the correctness of the data in the article.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Lawesson's Reagent could do this. It is useful to thionate a large number of carbonyl compounds including amides, so I think it can do for urea as well. I don't see any effect on a monosubstituted urea that would negatively affect the reaction.

[image: Thionation of carbonyl compounds by Lawesson's Reagent]